# Comparing elements of the same vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

The function below displays all the elements in the Car vector in the following order:

Car: #1

---

Make: BMW

Model: X6

Price (£): 50000

Car: #2

---

Make: Honda

Model: Jazz

Price (£): 13000

Car: #3

---

Make: Mazda

Model: 3

Price (£): 20000

etc

I would like to compare all the cars in the vector based on the price in order to find out which car is cheaper out of all the cars. Is there a Comparable method to compare the certain fields within the same vector?

This is a sample code:

```
   void displayCars(vector<Car> carVec)
   {
       if (!carVec.empty())
    {
    cout << "Current Inventory:\n";

    for (unsigned int count = 0; count < carVec.size(); count++)  
    {                                                             
        cout << "\t\t\tCar: #" << (count + 1) << endl          
             << "\t\t___________________________\n\n"
             << "Make: " << carVec[count].getMake() << endl
             << "Model: " << carVec[count].getModel() << endl
             << "Price (£): " << carVec[count].getPrice() << endl
             << endl << endl;
    }




}

}
```

Comment: No, you need to write one.

Comment: `void displayCars(vector<Car> carVec)` crates a copy of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use std::min_element:

```
auto min = std::min_element( begin(carVec), end(carVec), 
    [](const auto& lh, const auto& rh) {
        return lh.getPrice() < rh.getPrice();
});

std::cout << "Cheapest is: " << min->getModel() << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will always be sorting by the price, then you could do this:

```
class Car {
public:
  int price;
  std::string make;
  std::string model;
  int index;
  bool operator<(Car const& otherCar) const;
}

bool Car::operator<(Car const& otherCar) const
{
  return price < otherCar.price;
}
```

If you do it this way, then all the standard sorting algorithms on vectors will automatically sort using the price. Otherwise you can define separate functions on each thing you want to sort by:

```
bool IsCheaper(Car const& Car1, Car const& Car2)
{
   return Car1.price < Car2.price
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion also worked. Thank you. May I ask is there a way to print only the cheapest car as shown above by manni66? I have written a print method to print the values but it prints everything rather than just the cheapest car. The for loop: for(unsigned int i = 0; i < carVec.size(); i++)
        carVec.at(i).print();

Comment: With the operator< implemented, you should just be able to do auto min = std::min_element( begin(carVec), end(carVec)); with no lambda expression passed, and it will use operator< by default